# Firefox WebDriver not allowing await's in asynchronous scripts

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a simple web application with a set of accompanying Selenium tests. Before each test runs, I do a fetch of the user object by running `executeAsyncScript` as shown here:

```java
String getUserScript = "const callback = arguments.at(-1);\n" +
                       "const user = await fetch('/user');\n" +
                       "callback(user);";
jsExecutor.executeAsyncScript(getUserScript);
```

This works perfectly fine when run with Chrome or Edge as the browsers, but as soon as I try it with Firefox, the test fails with this error:

*SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions, async generators and modules*

I understand that in general, you need to mark a function as `async` in order to use `await` inside of it. But in this case, it works fine without wrapping my script in a pointless extra `async` function when using Chrome or Edge. Firefox is the only one that complains about it, so I was wondering if there are any Firefox WebDriver preferences or settings I may be missing that allow that script to work as-is? Thanks.

Comment: It is not pointless. I am amazed it is not erroring out in the other browsers.